# Calculating length along multiple line segments in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, linestring, length

I would like to calculate the distance between two points. They are connected with multiple line segments. Each LineString only consisting out of two points. How do I connect these LineString segments between my start and my end point to one single LineSting (of which I can calculate the length).

[image]

Comment: What have you tried with python?